# XML Deserialization into List

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I'm trying to deserialize an XML into a C# Object (containing an array of objects)

Here are the classes:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.1015")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute("I-collection", Namespace = "urn:xtk:queryDef", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class MyCollection
{

    private List<I> itemsField;

    public MyCollection()
    {
        this.itemsField = new List<I>();

    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("I", Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order = 0)]
    public List<I> Items
    {
        get
        {
            return this.itemsField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.itemsField = value;
        }
    }
}

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.1015")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class I
{

    private string EMAILField;

    private string FIRST_NAMEField;

    private string INDIVIDUAL_KEYField;

    private string LANGUAGE_CODEField;

    private string LAST_NAMEField;

    private string USERNAMEField;

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string EMAIL
    {
        get
        {
            return this.EMAILField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.EMAILField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string FIRST_NAME
    {
        get
        {
            return this.FIRST_NAMEField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.FIRST_NAMEField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string INDIVIDUAL_KEY
    {
        get
        {
            return this.INDIVIDUAL_KEYField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.INDIVIDUAL_KEYField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string LANGUAGE_CODE
    {
        get
        {
            return this.LANGUAGE_CODEField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.LANGUAGE_CODEField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string LAST_NAME
    {
        get
        {
            return this.LAST_NAMEField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.LAST_NAMEField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string USERNAME
    {
        get
        {
            return this.USERNAMEField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.USERNAMEField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Trying to deserialize

```
MyCollection result = Serialization.Deserialize<MyCollection>(xmle.OuterXml);
```

where xmle.OuterXml is

```
<I-collection xmlns="urn:xtk:queryDef">
  <I EMAIL="DFVCQD@DED.COM" FIRST_NAME="" INDIVIDUAL_KEY="5" LANGUAGE_CODE="ENG" LAST_NAME="" USERNAME="UPed" />
  <I EMAIL="GZPP@TM.COM" FIRST_NAME="" INDIVIDUAL_KEY="6" LANGUAGE_CODE="ENG" LAST_NAME="" USERNAME="GO" />
  <I EMAIL="IR0@MAIL.COM" FIRST_NAME="" INDIVIDUAL_KEY="7" LANGUAGE_CODE="ENG" LAST_NAME="" USERNAME="ir0" />
  <I EMAIL="QSNFA@QSA.COM" FIRST_NAME="" INDIVIDUAL_KEY="8" LANGUAGE_CODE="ENG" LAST_NAME="" USERNAME="UPlqfa" />
  <I EMAIL="JO7@HQ.COM" FIRST_NAME="" INDIVIDUAL_KEY="9" LANGUAGE_CODE="ENG" LAST_NAME="" USERNAME="jon17" />
  <I EMAIL="AUTO-CTU_AA4849_JIE@COOLIT.ORG" FIRST_NAME="" INDIVIDUAL_KEY="10" LANGUAGE_CODE="N/D" LAST_NAME="" USERNAME="ctu_aa4849_jie" />
  <I EMAIL="YVMPYEUFREZZPMLF@TKBYFGDPMYSKLZBB.COM" FIRST_NAME="" INDIVIDUAL_KEY="11" LANGUAGE_CODE="ENG" LAST_NAME="" USERNAME="rnopwakc" />
  <I EMAIL="ASDSD@SDAS.COM" FIRST_NAME="" INDIVIDUAL_KEY="12" LANGUAGE_CODE="ENG" LAST_NAME="" USERNAME="TRIsd" />
  <I EMAIL="U2@X.COM" FIRST_NAME="" INDIVIDUAL_KEY="13" LANGUAGE_CODE="ENG" LAST_NAME="" USERNAME="ll20373196" />
  <I EMAIL="W@W.TEST" FIRST_NAME="Sa" INDIVIDUAL_KEY="14" LANGUAGE_CODE="FRA" LAST_NAME="w" USERNAME="wsp" />
</I-collection>
```

Serialization.Deserialize does this:

```
public static T Deserialize<T>(string xml)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(xml))
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("xml");
            }


            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            using (StringReader stream = new StringReader(xml))
            {
                try
                {
                    return (T)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                { 
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to create object from xml string", ex);
                }
            }
        }
```

The problem is the object it returns is empty (I mean the itemsField List is empty). This deserialization should actually populate the list automatically using the data from the XML right ? or do I have to do it manually ?

Comment: Have you tried removing `Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified` ? Checking now...

Comment: That was the problem. Thanks!

Comment: if in doubt, cheat: `xsd my.xml` followed by `xsd my.xsd /c` will generate `my.cs`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Form` is incorrect; try:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("I", Order = 0)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"C:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            MyCollection myCollection = new MyCollection();

            XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyCollection.I_Collection));
            XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(FILENAME);
            MyCollection.I_Collection newRoot = (MyCollection.I_Collection)xs.Deserialize(reader);

        }
    }
    public partial class MyCollection
    {
        [XmlRoot("I-collection")]
        public class I_Collection
        {
            [XmlElement("I")]
            public List<I> itemsField { get; set; }

        }

        [XmlRoot("I")]
        public partial class I
        {
            [XmlAttribute("EMAIL")]
            public string EMAILField { get; set; }

            [XmlAttribute("FIRST_NAME")]
            public string FIRST_NAMEField { get; set; }

            [XmlAttribute("INDIVIDUAL_KEY")]
            public string INDIVIDUAL_KEYField { get; set; }

            [XmlAttribute("LANGUAGE_CODE")]
            public string LANGUAGE_CODEField { get; set; }

            [XmlAttribute("LAST_NAME")]
            public string LAST_NAMEField { get; set; }

            [XmlAttribute("USERNAME")]
            public string USERNAMEField { get; set; }
        }
    }



}
```